# How to properly replace multiple strings in a given file using PowerShell Replace

Tags: powershell, replace

I am simply trying to normalize values in a json file that later in the pipeline will be used as the parameters file to an ARM template.

I have tried using the "-Replace" parameter, and the ".Replace" method via individual calls for each replacement, and also via chained call for all replacements. Results are always the same, and they are NOT what I would expect.

The following code...

```
$TestFile = Get-Content -Path $ParameterPath -Raw

Write-Host "Replacing $($GeoTag) with $($GeographicTag)"
$TestFile = $TestFile.Replace($GeoTag, $GeographicTag)

Write-Host "Replacing $($RegionName01) with $($PrimaryRegion)"
$TestFile = $TestFile.Replace($RegionName01, $PrimaryRegion)

Write-Host "Replacing $($RegionName02) with $($SecondaryRegion)"
$TestFile = $TestFile.Replace($RegionName02, $SecondaryRegion)

Write-Host "Replacing $($AzLocation01) with $($PrimaryLocation)"
$TestFile = $TestFile.Replace($AzLocation01, $PrimaryLocation)

Write-Host "Replacing $($AzLocation02) with $($SecondaryLocation)"
$TestFile = $TestFile.Replace($AzLocation02, $SecondaryLocation)

Set-Content -Path $ParameterPath -Value $TestFile -NoNewLine
```

Produces the following **expected** result in console...

```
Replacing aS with AS
Replacing eaST with East
Replacing SouthEast with Southeast
Replacing EAST AsIa with eastasia
Replacing SoutH EAST AsIa with southeastasia
```

But then the following **not expected** result in file...

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "geoTag": {
            "value": "AS"
        },
        "regionName01": {
            "value": "eAST"
        },
        "regionName02": {
            "value": "Southeast"
        },
        "azLocation01": {
            "value": "eastasia"
        },
        "azLocation02": {
            "value": "SoutH eastasia"
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it that "eaST" is replaced by "eAST" instead of "East" in the file?

Why is it that "SoutH EAST AsIa" is replaced by "SoutH eastasia" instead of "southeastasia" in the file?

We know for a fact that the PowerShell variables hold the correct values, but for some reason the replacement occurs in a weird way and we don't get the expected values in the json file.

Comment: Your matches are overlapping. For example, “aS” exists in “aS” and “eaST”. So it is applying the replacements in order. If you reordered them, you would see a different result

Comment: @AdminOfThings Yes, that was it. I had to include the double quotes that encapsule my json's properties to avoid multiple matches like such. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the problem is with my logic.
I realized that right after posting.

The 1st replace, besides turning "aS" into "AS", also turns "eaST" into "eAST", which will now not match the 2nd replace, thus remaining as is.

The 4th replace, besides turning "EAST AsIa" into "eastasia", also turns "SoutH EAST AsIa" into "SoutH eastasia", which will now not match the 5th replace, thus remaining as is.

My logic was flawed, but at least my test data pointed that out. I managed to get it working as it should by including the double quotes in the replace match:

```
$TestFile = $TestFile.Replace("`"$($GeoTag)`"","`"$($GeographicTag)`"")
$TestFile = $TestFile.Replace("`"$($RegionName01)`"","`"$($PrimaryRegion)`"")
$TestFile = $TestFile.Replace("`"$($RegionName02)`"","`"$($SecondaryRegion)`"")
$TestFile = $TestFile.Replace("`"$($AzLocation01)`"","`"$($PrimaryLocation)`"")
$TestFile = $TestFile.Replace("`"$($AzLocation02)`"","`"$($SecondaryLocation)`"")
```